# Changing Start Address of Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

We are trying to boot linux on a zedboard and monitor all memory accesses through Programmable Logic. We're first trying to boot linux with a start address above `0x40000000` with:

```
$ make ARCH=arm UIMAGE_LOADADDR=0x48008000 uImage
```

So far, we're getting:

```
reading uImage
3453656 bytes read in 568 ms (5.8 MiB/s)
reading devicetree.dtb
9209 bytes read in 16 ms (561.5 KiB/s)
reading uramdisk.image.gz
5310018 bytes read in 865 ms (5.9 MiB/s)
memstart 0
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 43000000 ...
Image Name: Linux-3.18.0-xilinx-06434-g1f570
Image Type: ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
Data Size: 3453592 Bytes = 3.3 MiB
Load Address: 48008000
Entry Point: 48008000
Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 42000000 ...
Image Name:
Image Type: ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)
Data Size: 5309954 Bytes = 5.1 MiB
Load Address: 48000000
Entry Point: 48000000
Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 42a00000
Booting using the fdt blob at 0x42a00000
Loading Kernel Image ... OK
Loading Ramdisk to 1e812000, end 1ed22602 ... OK
Loading Device Tree to 1e80c000, end 1e8113f8 ... OK
## Transferring control to Linux (at address 48008000)...
Starting kernel ...
```

It looks like Linux hangs after trying to enable the mmu with the command:

```
mcr    p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0        @ write control reg
```

within `arch/arm/kernel/head.S`.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: You should provide more details. Where your RAM starts? What is the size of RAM? How did you figure that problem occurs when trying to execute that MMU enabling instruction? Are you 100% sure that it is so? Your question also stated that you just want to change start address of kernel: are you sure it's gonna fix your problem? Otherwise you should change your question. Also, what exactly do you mean saying `Start Address`?

Comment: can you use relocation? `CONFIG_RELOCATABLE=y`

Comment: Something goes wrong with identity mapping which Linux sets  before enable MMU. The problem could be everywhere, more details must be provided.